# "footer" div went under the "main" body div how can I set css cods?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 div in 3 row,
1-header div
2-main body div
3-footer dive

my problem is "footer" div went under the "main" body div
how can I set css cods?!

**HTML**

```
<div id="body">
    <div id="head-img">header</div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="main-body">
        <div id="main-body-left">
            <div id="main-body-left-top">
                <img src="img/pic.jpg" width="641" height="456" />
            </div>
            <div id="main-body-left-bottom">
                <div id="left-lin-box">1</div>
                <div id="middle">2</div>
                <div id="right-news-box">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="main-body-right">Right</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">foooooooooooooter</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#main-body {
    width:905px;
    background-color:#f8f7f3;
    clear:both;
}
#main-body-left {
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 1px 2px;
    display: inline;
    border:#900 1px solid
}
#main-body-right {
    float: right;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 2px 10px;
    display: inline;
}
#left-lin-box {
    float:left;
    width: 30%;
}
#middle {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
}
#right-news-box {
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
}
#footer {
    background-color:#393939;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: include relevant code pls!

Comment: ...and what do you mean by "footer div went under the main body div"...?

Comment: it`s like that main body div be z-index:1 and footer dive have z-index:2....

Comment: Please post your code in the question.

Comment: i post it in previus comment

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear the `float` property of you footer div. See the working demo ->

[**EDIT**](http://jsfiddle.net/S3ZRS/1/)

```css
#footer {
    clear:both; /* <-- added this line */
    background-color:#393939;
    height:50px;
}
```

Additional information on clearing floats [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)